# How do I specify that a subset of nodes needs to be fully connected?

Tags: z3, z3py

Consider a number of nodes with some connections between them.

My model's task is to color the nodes. One of the conditions is that the black nodes form a fully-connected set.

How do I code that?

NB: in case it matters: the connections between symbols are a precondition.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? Stack-overflow works the best if you show what you tried and where you got stuck. Based on how you model your graph, there could be many different ways.

Here’s a hint to get you started: in programming with z3, you usually write the code that “checks” the nodes are fully connected. Then, through the magic of constraint solving, that causes the solver to provide models that satisfy that criteria. So, start with modeling your graph and how you can check that the same-colored nodes are connected.

Note that hard problems like graph coloring, clique finding, isomorphisms etc remain hard in this realm too. They’re easier to code perhaps, but you shouldn’t expect better performance than exhaustive search for large instances on average; unless your graphs have special structure that the solver can exploit. But in that case, you’re better off using a custom algorithm anyhow, instead of relying on a general purpose SMT solver. Of course, this all depends on what your main goal is. It’s best to try multiple approaches and pick the one that performs the best.